# How can I make animation sprites (with rows and cols) work in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation

Example (you can modify and test): http://codepen.io/g-liu/pen/XbrMzr?editors=110

I've modified the code to work in Firefox, but the second animation seems to be skipping frames.

**frames**: http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/runningGrant.png

**html**:

```
<div id="guy-1" class="guy"></div>

<div id="guy-2" class="guy"></div>

<a href="http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/runningGrant.png" target="_BLANK">Original sprite</a>
```

**css:**

```
.guy {
  height: 294px;
  width: 165px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/runningGrant.png);
}

#guy-1 {
  animation: run-x 0.4s infinite steps(12);
}

#guy-2 {
  animation: run-x 0.4s infinite steps(12), run-y 2.4s infinite steps(6);
}

@keyframes run-x {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -1980px 0;
  }
}

@keyframes run-y {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 -1764px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Its because the last couple frames are empty, just add the little dude a couple more times to the end .

Comment: It's not that, what you said is the cause of a little blink during the animation.

Firefox doesn't work with background-position-x and background-position-y. That's why I've changed to background-position, but he just play the **run-y**

Answer (score -1):

I've solved my problem using LESS (http://lesscss.org/)

It maked the css of animation in a generic way that worked in all browsers (even in mobile).